# Is there a way to set actionBarTabTextStyle specifically for stacked action bar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I haven't been able to find a way to change the text style of tab text based on whether the `ActionBar` is stacked or not.  Only the background seems to be adjustable.

I am using [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/).  My `ActionBar` background is blue with white text.  I am using tabbed navigation, so when the tabs portion is stacked below the main `ActionBar`, I want the background to be white (which I've done using `abBackgroundStacked`).  This makes the text invisible (text is same color as background).  I want the text to be black when the actionbar is stacked.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a stacked ActionBar, then the tabs are stacked in portrait and part of the ActionBar in landscape.

Then just make a style specifically for portrait, than has black text on white stacked tabs and a style for landscape mode which has white text on the blue ActionBar+tabs.

Write each style into a separate styles.xml file and place it accordingly in values and values-land (for landscape) folders. That's what I've done and it works perfectly.